# Using like with a jasper parameter

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports, wildcard

I'm trying to use 'like' with a parameter in Jasper.

My query is:

```
... where tb_produto.NomeProduto LIKE $P{NomeProduto} order by $P!{OrdenarPor}
```

When I put the name of parameter $P{NomeProduto} = ABC in preview dialog, I get my product, 
but when I use a wildcard doesn't work.

$P{NomeProduto} = AB%  or A% or just % return no rows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the same syntax like you did in your order by clause. In your case it is necessary to treat the parameter "as is" (unbound parameter) like that:

```
...
where
    tb_produto.NomeProduto LIKE '%$P!{NomeProduto}%'
order by
    $P!{OrdenarPor}
```

More details about that: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/

But you have to take care about SQL injection when the parameter is given from outside (e.g. a webform), because this way the query could be manipulated easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want search Like:  .......where empId like '822A%' then you can use
concat japser parameter to wildcard like: where empId like '$P!{p_empId}%'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
where  tblName.colName LIKE "%"'$P!{paramName}'"%"
```